# Xcode syntax highlighting making text jump around

Tags: xcode

When I am typing in Xcode syntax highlighting is making the text jump around with each keystroke. It's like it is reevaluating the entire line each time. The video below shows what I am talking about, the amount it makes the line jump around while I type in `"thePath"` and `"txt"` by styling and restyling `Bundle.main.path` is maddening.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image: Typing a line with syntax highlight going weird]

Comment: Looks like you just have different font sizes set for different types of things. Change that.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Caswell was right, I had increased the test size for plain text and not any of the formatted text styles